# how to view source code of programs (python)

Tags: python

Python newbie here....I was interested in writing a basic touch typing tutor program in python.  I was wondering what is the best way to download source code of applications that people have written that are of a similar nature (to use as a guide to learn from).  I went to http://pypi.python.org/ and downloaded some packages but I'm not quite sure how to view the actual python code.  Which file are you supposed to open.  I found a run.py file in one of them and it doesn't seem to even work when I try to run it.  I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Thanks!

Comment: View your files in your favourite text editor. I like Notepad++, but there are a gazillion different editors.

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close it as "not a real question". It is not difficult to tell what OP is asking here. Sure, it is a simple question but OP has noted that he/she is a newbie. Just give a simple answer and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-clicking a .py script will execute the script (and may not send any useful results to the screen). To view the source you can open a .py file with IDLE (which comes with Python) or even Notepad although a more advanced text editor or IDE is recommended.  See [Is there a good, free Python IDE for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows) for IDE recommendations by the stackoverflow community.  Good luck, and welcome to the Python community!

Comment: @ Dhaivat Pandya seriously?  Most of those IDEs exist on all popular platforms...and I bet you $10 he on windows.

Comment: a) Double clicking .py scripts don't execute on Linux
b) He probably is on Windows, but, do you know already?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `inspect` to view the code from the interpreter.  So say your file is named "test.py" and it's on your `PYTHONPATH` (if you don't know what that is, then make sure you are in the same directory as "test.py").

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import test  # this imports test.py
>>> print inspect.getsource(test)   
def hello(name):
  print("Hello %s" % name)
```

If you were using `IPython`, then you could also do:

```
In [1]: import test
In [2]: test??
```

You can't edit the code like this... but you can view it.

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a README explaining things.

If not, the src/ directory is where you should start looking and open some files with a text editor like Notepad++.